# Sending binary files over sockets

Tags: sockets, c++11, binaryfiles, fstream, ofstream

I want to send a binary file over from client to server using sockets.
This is my code for reading the file:

```
  size_t buffer_size = 512;
        std::fstream myfile;
        myfile.open(filePath[i], std::ios::in | std::ios::out | 
                     std::ios::binary);
        std::vector<char> myBuffer(512);
        std::ostream_iterator<char> osIt(std::cout);
        //std::ifstream myfile(filePath[i]);
        while (myfile)
        {
            myfile.read(&myBuffer.front(), buffer_size);
            if (!myfile)
            {
                myBuffer.resize(myfile.gcount());
            }
            std::string msg(myBuffer.begin(), myBuffer.end());
            doLog("sending message");
            sout << locker << "\n  " << msg.c_str() << unlocker;
            q_.enQ(msg);
            ::Sleep(10 * id());  // sleep time increases with each    
                             addition Sender
            if (pSt->status() == "bad")
                break;
        }
```

I am using BLOCKING queue and also reading the file block by bloxk with each block size as 512.

This is my code for saving file at the server side:

```
                            msg = q_.deQ();
            std::ofstream myStream;

                   myStream.open("../Test/Client1/Received_Files/darkKnight.jpeg",  
                            std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
            myStream << msg;
            if (msg == "stop\n"){
                myStream.close();
            }
```

I am not able to open the output image that is created.

Answer (score 0):

- String is not a container for binary data. Just read and write bytes.
- I wouldn't use the stream classes for this, or indeed anything above read(), write(), send(), and recv(), unless you have a proper sockets class library available.